# Wordpress theme works very strange in IE

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

I'm working with WP website now and stuck with one problem.

The website is working fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera and IE10, but in older IE versions (like IE9) it looks very strange. It seems that my custom CSS doesn't loaded properly. The interesting thing is that CSS styles partly applied to the website (icon font) but not styles which overrrides Foundation framework styles.

Maybe someone can explain me what I'm doing wrong and put me into right direction?

P.S. I'm not sure that it's important, but I based my WP theme on [Foundation WP theme](http://fwp.drewsymo.com/).

Thank you in advance!

- Alex

Comment: How many stylesheet files are you loading? Older IE versions have a fairly tight limit on the number of CSS files that can be loaded into a single page, and will throw away anything over that limit. (There's also a limit on the number of selectors in a CSS file). If you have a lot of files, you should consider merging them. (this would be good practice anyway, to cut down on the number of http requests your page load has to make)

Comment: I counted 7 css files. Some of them are used from additional plugins so unfortunately I can't merge them into a single CSS file. Thank you for answer)

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. The problem appeared because the main CSS file was too large for IE8 and lower, and it just croped my CSS styles. I've brake it into 2 files and this fixed the problem :) Thank you again Spudley!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appeared because the main CSS file was too large for IE8 and lower, and it just croped my CSS styles. I've broke it into 2 files and this fixed the problem :)

Thank you everyone who tried to help, and especially Spudley for pointing into right direction!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding this to the top of the head tag above the title tag to make sure IE uses the highest version in IE

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

also when viewing in IE are you checking the in the inspector (F12) making sure the Document Mode matches the Browser Mode so if your checking IE9.. you would

**Browser Mode:** IE9

**Document Mode:** IE9 Standards

Comment: Thank you for answer Johnatan :) I added this line to the header but nothing changed. And yes, browser mode is equal to the document mode.

Comment: @Nekto what is your Operating System and version of IE your using?

Comment: I've tested it on IE9, Win7

Comment: is it IE10, but Browser Mode is at IE9 .. or is IE9 standalone?

Comment: It's a standalone IE9 version. I didn't upgrade it to be able to test websites for some "gourmet" customers :) Anyway thank you for suggestion, I appreciate it.

Comment: you should be able to get an accurate rendering with IE10 rendering in Browser Mode: IE9, Document Mode: IE9 standards .. BUT in some cases the rendering modes are different.. for example standalone IE8 renders in some cases different than IE10 rendering Browser Mode: IE8, Document Mode: IE8 standards .. so i can see your dilemma.. IE is a real pain to debug with all its different rendering modes that work different depending on the OS and IE version

Comment: Yes, IE is the most pain-maker for all developers :)

Answer (score 0):

The class .dl-menu is using the code:

opacity: 0;

Which is not very cross browser.  You need to use a few versions for better support of opacity.

This is only the one point, and it looks like there may be others to me, but see if changing this helps you.

This page will explain the cross browser opacity properties well: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Comment: Thank you for suggestion Owen, I'll fix it. But unfortunately this will not help to fix this problem.